# SSIS Project Destination Assistant "unable to use" Existing Connection Managers

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019, SSIS project.

Whenever I drop a new Destination Assistant into a Data Flow I am required to create a new Connection Manager to our SQL Server instance.

Presently, there are 4 identical Data Connections (except the index appended on the name) and none of them show up in the list of "Select connection managers." TBH this is driving me nuts. It is the same behavior for both Package and Project scoped Connection Managers.

Any ideas? Everything I see everywhere just shows the Database connection managers listed as expected - but they don't show up for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the assistants. Not to be flippant but I don't find that they add any value. I know whether I'm pushing/pulling from a flat file vs OLE DB so why do I want to make clicks here versus just dragging the thing I want onto my palette?

Whenever I start SSIS work on a new machine, I remove the suggested favorites of source/destination assistants and add in what I use day-in and day-out.

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I haven't ever tried that. I'll give it a go Monday and streamline the workspace. Thanks for the idea - not flippant at all if it works.